# pop up style dialog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a pop up button that is loaded with 5 options programicically, if a particular option is selected, lets say, "append the end of file name",then my update function needs to cause a small pop up window with a textField and a save and cancel button to appear. I don't know how to do this.
I was able to get a nice NSAlert example to work but it does not take a textField that I know of.
Is there a dialog class or some other modal I should be using or should I be trying to create a second nib? in either case I don't really know how to do it so a good example or tutorial would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just searched around, and there is a method someone found to display an NSAlert with an NSTextField, buttons and get the text the user has just typed. It's [here, on the Macrumors forums, slightly old..](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=5719665&postcount=2)

Essentially you could just go with:

```
NSString *prompt = @"Please enter text to append to file name:";
NSString *infoText = @"What happens here is...";
NSString *defaultValue = @"Default Value";

NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText: prompt
                                 defaultButton:@"Save"
                               alternateButton:@"Cancel"
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:infoText];

NSTextField *input = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 24)];
[input setStringValue:defaultValue];
[alert setAccessoryView:input];
NSInteger button = [alert runModal];
if (button == NSAlertDefaultReturn) {
    [input validateEditing];
    NSLog(@"User entered: %@", [input stringValue]);
} else if (button == NSAlertAlternateReturn) {
    NSLog(@"User cancelled");
} else {
    NSLog(@"bla");
}
```

That code would display the NSAlert, with customisable prompt, informative text and default value for the NSTextField, plus log what the user entered, whether they cancelled, etc.

Hope that works! :)

Comment: I tried this code and it looks pretty professional even if it is old. Two things I'm not getting though is a setting for location relative to the window that opened it(I read a post that said that requires to move to a "sheet"?) and a size setting for the box(much less important)