# osx Add inputs to NSAlert

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I would like to use a NSAlert in my OSX application to deal with user authentication.

The answer to this question [pop up style dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905197/pop-up-style-dialog) covers the basics but I can't figure out how to expand a accessoryView to include two inputs and a label for each.

This produces a single text input:

```
NSAlert *myAlertView = [[NSAlert alloc]init];

NSTextField *input = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 24)];
[input setStringValue:@""];
[myAlert setAccessoryView:input];
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the point where you start needing to add inputs, what you are creating is no longer an alert dialog. Create a NSPanel in the Interface Builder with the necessary controls and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looking into the NSPanel solution now.  Seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Sorry, but NSPanels (at least as they come in IB) lack lot's of "NSAlert"ness. The standard text size and alignment, the severity icon, much more. Also, when used as a sheet - NSPanels loose their title, so you actually have to set up everything within the NSPanel's content view